# TSQL Set theory

Tags: sql-server-2005

Here is the question

You are to label the dice sides with numbers.  Each dice has 6 sides. You have two dice.  You must label so that you can display (not sum or product) the numbers 0 to 31.  Complete output:

```
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
```

I tried

```
(select
       0 as dice1 union
       select 1 union
       select 2 union
       select 3 union
       select 4 union
       select 5 )

    join

(select
       0 as dice2 union
       select 1 union
       select 2 union
       select 3 union
       select 4 union
       select 5 )
```

I don't know how to process it further.Help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't know. You're definitely going to need 6,7,8,9 on one or other of the dice. But 0,1 and 2 need to be on both dice which only leaves 6 slots for 7 numbers! Maybe you have to turn the 6 upside down to get 9. Not a lot to do with SQL Server 2005 anyway!

Comment: Classic problem with realization as "continuous calenders" made of wooden blocks that you sometimes see at banks. The problem is strictly over-constrained and is solved with 6/9 ambiguity just as @Martin suggests. But not, in anyway a programming problem and o off topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin mentioned in his comment, the key to solving this problem is to use the upside down 6 for a 9. See: [solution: calendar cubes](http://www.techinterview.org/Solutions/fog0000000138.html)

As for a programmatic T-SQL solution, perhaps:

```
declare @Dice1 table (
    side int
)

insert into @Dice1
    (side)
    select 0 union all
    select 1 union all
    select 2 union all
    select 3 union all
    select 4 union all
    select 5

declare @Dice2 table (
    side int
)

insert into @Dice2
    (side)
    select 0 union all
    select 1 union all
    select 2 union all
    select 6 union all
    select 7 union all
    select 8 union all
    select 9 /* Upside down 6 */


select CAST(d1.side as CHAR(1)) + CAST(d2.side as CHAR(1)) as MyDate
    from @Dice1 d1
        cross join @Dice2 d2
    where d1.side * 10 + d2.side <= 31
union
select CAST(d2.side as CHAR(1)) + CAST(d1.side as CHAR(1)) as MyDate
    from @Dice1 d1
        cross join @Dice2 d2
    where d2.side * 10 + d1.side <= 31
order by MyDate
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. It's `0 1 2 3 4 5` and `0 1 2 7 8 6`.

Comment: @Denis: Years and years of drinking Microsoft Kool-Aid: My Documents, My Downloads, ..., MyDate. :-)

Comment: haha, but those are numbers, not dates!